# Split a row into multiple rows - Teradata

Tags: teradata

Below is an example of my table

```
Names   Start_Date   Orders    Items
AAA     2020-01-01   300       100
BAA     2020-02-01   896       448
```

My requirement would be as below

```
Names   Start_Date   Orders   
AAA     2020-01-01   100   
AAA     2020-01-01   100
AAA     2020-01-01   100
BBB     2020-02-01   448
BBB     2020-02-01   448
```

The rows should be split based on the (Orders/Items) value

Comment: What if orders are not a multiple of items, e.g. 350 - 100?

Comment: @dnoeth - It can be rounded off to the nearest integer

Comment: And how many rows do you want for the 350/100 example, three or four? 300/300/300 or 300/300/300/50?

Comment: @dnoeth -  It can be four- 100/100/100/100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice task for Teradata's SQL extension to create time series (based on @Andrew's test data):

```
SELECT *
FROM vt_foo
EXPAND ON PERIOD(start_date, start_date + Cast(Ceiling(Cast(orders AS FLOAT)/items) AS INT)) AS pd
```

For an exact split of orders into items:

```
SELECT dt.*, 
   CASE WHEN items * (end_date - start_date) > orders 
        THEN orders MOD items
        ELSE items
   end
FROM
 (
   SELECT t.*, End(pd) AS end_date
   FROM vt_foo AS t
   EXPAND ON PERIOD(start_date, start_date + Cast(Ceiling(Cast(orders AS FLOAT)/items) AS INT)) AS pd 
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: I don't use expand much, this is a clever use of it.  I'm assuming it's cheaper than a recursive cte?

Comment: @Andrew: Way cheaper, an input row is processed locally within an AMP and simply returned multiple times. Try it with 1000000 orders and 10 items :-)

Comment: @dnoeth - Perfect! This code worked like a charm(Expand on period). Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This calls for a recursive CTE.  Here's how I'd approach it, with a lovely volatile table for some sample data.

```
    create volatile table vt_foo
    (names varchar(100), start_date date, orders int, items int)
    on commit preserve rows;

    insert into vt_foo values ('AAA','2020-01-01',300,100);
    insert into vt_foo values ('BAA','2020-02-01',896,448);
    insert into vt_foo values ('CCC','2020-03-01',525,100);  -


    with recursive cte (names, start_date,items, num, counter) as (
    select
    names,
    start_date,
    items,
round(orders /( items * 1.0) ) as num ,
    1 as counter
    from vt_foo
    UNION ALL
    select
    a.names,
    a.start_date,
    a.items,
    b.num,
    b.counter + 1
    from vt_foo a
    inner join cte b 
    on a.names = b.names
    and a.start_date =b.start_date
    where b.counter + 1 <= b.num
    )
    select  * from cte
    order by names,start_date
```

This bit:  `b.counter + 1 <= b.num` is the key to limiting the output to the proper # of rows per product/date.

I think this should be ok, but test it with small volumes of data.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew. This code worked for fewer values but for higher ranges I started getting numeric overflow issues.